# Getting deadlock while calling @Transactional method inside callable thread

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Getting deadlock while calling @Transactional method inside callable thread

we have method like below,

```
@Service
public class ClassA {

@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public void serviceClassMethod()
{
   //Did some DB delete or update operations
}
}

@Service
Class ClassB
{
@Autowired
private ClassA classA;

private DetailsBean sendRequest(DetailsBean detailsBean)
{
classA.serviceClassMethod();
return new DetailsBean();
}
private void submitDeleteAndResetTask(DetailsBean detailsBean,
            List<Future<DetailsBean>> mmFutureResponseList, String userId, String reason) {
        Callable<DetailsBean> callableObj = () -> {

            DetailsBean detailsBean = sendRequest(detailsBean);
            return detailsBean;
        };
        Future<DetailsBean> detailsBean = matchmakerExecutor.submit(callableObj);
        mmFutureResponseList.add(detailsBean);
    }

}
```

```
org.springframework.dao.CannotAcquireLockException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:289) ~[spring-orm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:255) ~[spring-orm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:538) ~[spring-orm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743) ~[spring-tx-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711) ~[spring-tx-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:633) ~[spring-tx-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:386) ~[spring-tx-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at com.struct.bo.packapp.services.DeleteRphyDetails$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ad4e572.deleteRphyDetailsByMAC(<generated>) ~[classes!/:0.82.0]
    at com.struct.bo.packapp.services.DeleteRphyDetails.sendDeleteResetRequest(DeleteRphyDetails.java:315) ~[classes!/:0.82.0]
    at com.struct.bo.packapp.services.DeleteRphyDetails.lambda$submitDeleteAndResetTask$10(DeleteRphyDetails.java:296) ~[classes!/:0.82.0]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle8iDialect$3.convert(Oracle8iDialect.java:565) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar!/:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar!/:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar!/:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar!/:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:200) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar!/:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:46) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar!/:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3572) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar!/:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3832) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar!/:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityDeleteAction.execute(EntityDeleteAction.java:124) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar!/:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar!/:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar!/:5.4.20.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar!/:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:348) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar!/:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar!/:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar!/:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1363) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar!/:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:454) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar!/:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3213) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar!/:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2381) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar!/:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:447) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar!/:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar!/:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar!/:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar!/:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar!/:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:534) ~[spring-orm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:509) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:461) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1104) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:550) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:268) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:655) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:270) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:91) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:970) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1205) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3666) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeInternal(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1426) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3756) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3736) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1063) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar!/:5.4.20.Final]
    ... 36 common frames omitted
Caused by: oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:513) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
    ... 53 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

When locking, be sure to define how long you want to wait ( if at all).

Example is via the entityManager. There is also the @Lock annotation

```
entityManager.setLockMode(lockMode ?: LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
    .setHint("javax.persistence.lock.timeout", duration ?: LockOptions.WAIT_FOREVER)
```